# VS Code disable Tree view Find (Explorer search)

Tags: visual-studio-code

A lot of times I simply want to trigger a search in my currently open file. Since a few versions however, when pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> a new *Tree view Find* (Explorer search) opens up in the explorer view. I do not need this and it is distracting because I have to manually set the focus back onto my file and press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> again. How can I disable this feature?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

After a bit of digging, I found the solution myself.
Under Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts search for *list.find*
There is one entry with a binding on <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. Right click and Remove Keybinding will do the job.
However, there is still a binding on <kbd>F3</kbd> to trigger opening the Tree view Find.

Comment: Works well, just make sure that you search for `list.find` and not be lazy like me and search for just `find` and delete that one . If you are brain challenged (like me) and do this (like me), you can add it back by editing the system [keybindings as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33791097/how-can-i-change-keyboard-shortcut-bindings-in-visual-studio-code) and removing that has `"command": "-actions.find"`

Answer (score 1):

[image: VS code Keyboard Shortcuts]

Edit keyboard shortcuts like on screenshot, and ctrl+f will work only in editor.

(File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts)

Answer (score 0):

This has been annoying me so much recently, I finally decided to change it and landed here. However, as pointed out in other answers, simply disabling `list.find` shortcut is not enough for me as it doesn't trigger "Find" on the open file when focus is in tree view, which is something I wanted. Perhaps something changed in newer versions.

For that, you can change the `When` condition for the keybinding, to also trigger on `listFocus`.

Under Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts, search for `list.find` where the keybinding is `⌘ F`, remove (right click, then click on Remove keybinding) or change it to whatever you want.

Then, search for `actions.find`, right click, then click on "Change When Expression", replace `editorFocus || editorIsOpen` with `editorFocus || editorIsOpen || listFocus`.

[Image showing the changed condition for keybinding for `Find`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3lmk.png)